# How to make an android app reachable without repreatedly polling from a server?

Tags: android, service, polling, standby

How can some service-style (long running) android apps be reachable over network although they do no polling from a server?

The info on Theis Borg's app *Android Lost* says:

> The app does no polling to a server, so there is no extra battery usage.

( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=en )

I would like to find out how to write such apps.

(For broader audience, I've also posted this question on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61453/how-to-continually-communicate-without-repreatedly-polling-from-a-server))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) provides this functionality. The Google Services Framework app (preinstalled on most Android devices) connects to Google servers and keeps that connection as long as the Android device has Internet connectivity; this single connection is used to receive incoming GCM messages for all installed apps which use GCM, and the app which handles the message is started on demand — so it does not even need to be running in the background.